# Некорректно работает сдвиг курсора при захвате объекта (Drag and Drop)

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Взял пример реализации Drag and Drop из учебника, но столкнулся с тем, что у меня работает по-другому.
Необходимо сделать так чтобы при клике на перетаскиваемый объект происходил захват в том же месте куда кликнули, без перескакиваний курсора.

Задача простая, но я ломаю голову не первый день.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 
</head>

<style>
 div{
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 10%;
  padding: 10%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  position: absolute;
 }
 div.area-1{
  margin-left: 10%;
 }
 div.area-2{
  margin-left: 50%; 
 }
 .circle{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
 }
</style>
<body>
<div class="area-1">
 <figure class="circle" id="first">1</figure>
    <figure class="circle">2</figure>
    <figure class="circle">3</figure>
    <figure class="circle">4</figure>
</div>
<div class="area-2"></div>
<script>
//центрировать курсор


var ball = document.getElementById('first');
ball.onmousedown = function(e) { // 1. отследить нажатие
  
  var coords=ball.getBoundingClientRect();
//console.log("Top:"+br.top+", Left:"+br.left+", Right:"+br.right+", Bottom:"+br.bottom);

   //onmousedown
   //левая верхняя граница мячика полученную при помощи функции (координаты)
   shiftX = e.clientX - coords.left;
   shiftY = e.clientY - coords.top;
  

  // подготовить к перемещению
  // 2. разместить на том же месте, но в абсолютных координатах
  ball.style.position = 'absolute';
  moveAt(e);
  // переместим в body, чтобы мяч был точно не внутри position:relative
  document.body.appendChild(ball);

  ball.style.zIndex = 1000; // показывать мяч над другими элементами

  // передвинуть мяч под координаты курсора
  // и сдвинуть на половину ширины/высоты для центрирования
  function moveAt(e) {
    ball.style.left = e.pageX - ball.offsetWidth+ 'px';
    ball.style.top = e.pageY - ball.offsetHeight + 'px';
   
    //console.log(ball.offsetWidth, ball.offsetHeight);
    //console.log( ball.style.left,  ball.style.top);
  }

  // 3, перемещать по экрану
  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    moveAt(e);
  }

  // 4. отследить окончание переноса
  ball.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    ball.onmouseup = null;
  }

  //убрать тень объекта при перетаскивании
  ball.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Прикрепите html часть для сниппета

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('circle'), function(ball) {
  ball.onmousedown = function(e) {      
    var coords = ball.getBoundingClientRect()
      // +40 - поправка на дефолтные стили для figure элемента.
      , shiftX = e.clientX - coords.left + 40
      // +16 - поправка на дефолтные стили для figure элемента.
      , shiftY = e.clientY - coords.top + 16;
    ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
    ball.style.position = 'absolute';
    moveAt(e);
    document.body.appendChild(ball);
    function moveAt(e) {
      ball.style.left = e.pageX - shiftX + 'px';
      ball.style.top = e.pageY - shiftY + 'px';
    }
    document.onmousemove = function(e) {
      moveAt(e);
    }
    document.onmouseup = function() {
      document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
    }
    ball.ondragstart = function() {
      return false;
    };
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
}
    
div.area-1 {
  margin-left: 10%;
}
    
div.area-2 {
  margin-left: 50%; 
}
    
.circle {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="area-1">
  <figure class="circle" id="first">1</figure>
  <figure class="circle">2</figure>
  <figure class="circle">3</figure>
  <figure class="circle">4</figure>
</div>
<div class="area-2"></div>
```